Google Secret Manager with GKE and external secrets error: could not get idbindtoken
I'm in the process of moving to secret manager with external secrets operator in our GKE Standard Cluster.
I have been getting the below error and I am struggling to see why this is happening:
failed to create GCP secretmanager client: unable to fetch identitybindingtoken: could not get idbindtoken token, status: 404

What is causing this and how to troubleshoot it?
terraform:
resource "google_service_account" "external_secret_sa" {
  account_id  = "external-secrets-sa"
  description = "Service Account for external secrets"
  project     = var.project_id
}

# Gives the external secrets Service account access to token creator
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "external_secret_sa_token_creator" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.external_secret_sa.email}"
  ]
}
# Gives the external secrets Service account access to the secret manager. 
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "external_secret_sa_access" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.external_secret_sa.email}"
  ]
}

#Allow kubernetes service account to impersonate GCP service account
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "external_secret_sa_bind" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.external_secret_sa.name
  role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${var.project_id}.svc.id.goog[external-secrets/${google_service_account.external_secret_sa.account_id}]"
  ]
  depends_on = [google_service_account.external_secret_sa]
}

helm chart config for external-secrets (its a dependency in another chart)
external-secrets:
  installCRDs: true
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name: external-secrets-sa
    annotations:
      iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: "external-secrets-sa@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"


ClusterSecretStore:
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterSecretStore
metadata:
  name: gcp-secret-store
spec:
  provider:
    gcpsm:
      projectID: {{ .Values.projectId }}
      auth:
        workloadIdentity:
          # name of the cluster Location, region or zone
          clusterLocation: {{ .Values.region }}
          # name of the GKE cluster
          clusterName: {{ .Values.gkeCluster }}
          # reference the sa from above
          serviceAccountRef:
            name: {{ index .Values "external-secrets" "serviceAccount" "name" }}
            namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}

GKE pool oauth scope:
node_pools_oauth_scopes = {
    all = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"

    ]
  }

I feel like the binding between GKE and workload identity SA isn't working as it should, but im not sure if its an issue with GKE cluster or somewhere else.

Running into similar issue today. Weird!

Idk if you have the same issue, but in my case the region was wrong.

I got the same issue when I was running the secret store with an incorrect cluster name defined.
I would update your config such as :

adding ns where secret store will run ( in metadata )
adding ProjectID where secret store will run ( in wokrloadIdentity )

Note that first ProjectID ref is where is GCPSM is running, second is where Secret Store is running, which can be different.
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterSecretStore
metadata:
  name: gcp-secret-store
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  provider:
    gcpsm:
      projectID: {{ .Values.projectId }}
      auth:
        workloadIdentity:
          # name of the cluster Location, region or zone
          clusterLocation: {{ .Values.region }}
          # name of the GKE cluster
          clusterName: {{ .Values.gkeCluster }}
          #name of the ProjectID where SecretStore is running
          projectID: {{ .Values.projectId }}
          # reference the sa from above
          serviceAccountRef:
            name: {{ index .Values "external-secrets" "serviceAccount" "name" }}
        

